# Embed AMF metadata into MP4 with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

Is it possible to manually embed timed text metadata into MP4 files?
I have a TTML / SRT file with the metadata. I just need to embed the text data without doing anything to the video/audio tracks.

We used to do the metadata injecting using a plugin on Wowza streaming engine which we use for live streaming.

What I need to do is manually inject the metadata in to prerecorded MP4 files without running the video through Wowza.

Here is one such video file **that was processed by Wowza**:

```
ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1b62a60] multiple fourcc not supported
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'metadata-back.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : f4v 
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42m4v 
    creation_time   : 2015-04-16 11:12:39
  Duration: 00:00:11.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1373 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1352 kb/s, 28.60 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-16 11:12:39
      handler_name    : WowzaStreamingEngine
      encoder         : WowzaStreamingEngine
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: speex (spex / 0x78657073), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 17 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-16 11:12:39
      handler_name    : WowzaStreamingEngine
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (amf0 / 0x30666D61), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-04-16 11:12:39
      handler_name    : WowzaStreamingEngine
At least one output file must be specified
```

I found with help from stackoverflow that I can use `ffmpeg` to do the trick.

So I run the command

`ffmpeg -i video_without_data.mp4 -i sub.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

and if I run `ffmpeg -i out.mp4`, I get this:

```
ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
  libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
  libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
  Duration: 00:00:07.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 925 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1366x768 [SAR 1:1 DAR 683:384], 920 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SubtitleHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

Now as you can see the text is embedded with a different codec (is this the right term?). Also I dont see an audio track as well.

Hope my question is clear enough. I need a way to embed metadata (from srt / ttml) into an MP4 video it should be embedded in `amf` format (again is this the right term?)

Comment: You should include the **complete** console output from each command; not just segments.

Comment: oh!!. I've edited my question and added the entire output. Thanks @LordNeckbeard. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem: FFmpeg doesn't have a specific AMF (Action Message Format) muxer/encoder -- at least not currently -- so there's no *true* way to use it to create an **"amf0" data stream** in your output file to mirror Wowza's results.

What your current script is doing is taking whatever data's present in your SRT file and muxing it into your video as a **subtitle** stream in a 3GPP Timed Text (mov_text) format.

If this is the result you're expecting (per the info you gained from Stack Overflow), then it's working as intended. However, your current script is dropping the audio stream due to a lack of `-map` parameters, which are needed whenever whenever attempting to mux from two or more input files. You should change it to the following:

`ffmpeg -i video_without_data.mp4 -i sub.srt -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c copy -c:s mov_text -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

If dumping your metadata into a subtitle stream *isn't* what you intended, you might try using FFmpeg's **metadata** demuxer/muxer to see if your AMF data can be read from an existing file, then reformatted and muxed into new vids. Details can be found at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Metadata-1